# MySQL Query ORDER BY certain values before others

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I am developing a game highscore where the time of completion is stored in a database, but if you don't complete the level but save your highscore, the completion time is 0.

I am trying to make a query which lists the highscore with the lowest completion time first, but my simple `ORDER BY` is sticking all of the 0 completion times at the start of course!

Is there any way I can order it like this, but have the 0's at the bottom.

I have tried:

`SELECT FROM highscores ORDER BY completiontime > 0, completiontime = 0 ASC`

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible to change the design so that incomplete levels have completion time null instead of zero?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM highscores
ORDER BY completiontime = 0, completiontime
```