# MySQL Sorting Ranking List with positon 0

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I am trying to sort a ranking list of sports players, all of which have a ranking position. However, some are new on tour, so their ranking is 0. If I simply order by position ASC the 0's will appear first, I would like them to appear after the rest. I have tried something like:

```
SELECT * FROM rankings WHERE season='$season' ORDER BY CASE position = 0 THEN 999, ELSE position ASC
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Query ORDER BY certain values before others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371193/mysql-query-order-by-certain-values-before-others)

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would like the output to look. I don't know if I completely follow how you want the structure to look.

Answer (score 2):

You can handle it strictly in the `ORDER BY` clause

```
SELECT * 
FROM rankings 
WHERE season='$season' 
ORDER BY (position=0) ASC, position ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT *, (CASE position WHEN 0 THEN 999 ELSE position) AS custom_sort FROM rankings WHERE season='$season' ORDER BY custom_sort ASC
```