# Putting one specific letter before all others in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently using:

```
SELECT * FROM OptSubjectItems ORDER BY yr, subject;
```

to get some information from a database. That works fine, except that I need to have records where yr=*x* first, then the others, sorted by year and subject. I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM OptSubjectItems ORDER BY yr=*x*, yr, subject;
```

from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371193/mysql-query-order-by-certain-values-before-others), but that shows things where yr=*x* last, rather than first.

Thanks,
Jamie McClymont

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are nearly the solution. Just a addition

```
SELECT * FROM OptSubjectItems ORDER BY (yr=x) DESC, subject DESC;
```

Comment: That dosn't work for me. It puts *yr=x* last, and the rest are ordered by subject rather than yr then subject

Comment: Thanks! I actually had to use `(yr=13) DESC, yr, subject` (note the `yr, `) to get it to work

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM OptSubjectItems ORDER BY 
case when yr=x then 0 else 1 end, yr, subject
```